# In python, is math.acos() faster than numpy.arccos() for scalars?

Tags: python, math, numpy

I'm doing some scientific computing in Python with a lot of geometric calculations, and I ran across a significant difference between using `numpy` versus the standard `math` library.

```
>>> x = timeit.Timer('v = np.arccos(a)', 'import numpy as np; a = 0.6')
>>> x.timeit(100000)
0.15387153439223766
>>> y = timeit.Timer('v = math.acos(a)', 'import math; a = 0.6')
>>> y.timeit(100000)
0.012333301827311516
```

That's more than a 10x speedup!  I'm using numpy for almost all standard math functions, and I just assumed it was optimized and at least as fast as `math`.  For long enough vectors, numpy.arccos() will eventually win vs. looping with math.acos(), but since I only use the scalar case, is there any downside to using math.acos(), math.asin(), math.atan() across the board, instead of the numpy versions?

Comment: It might make more sense to test this with arrays, rather than scalars. That's what numpy is optimized for.

Comment: "since I only use the scalar case" - then either your application is completely unsuited for NumPy, or you've implemented your application in a very inefficient manner. NumPy is all about arrays.

Comment: I'd assume it's because math.acos is a builtin function, meant for scalars, whereas numpy ufuncs like np.arccos have overhead relating to dealing with arrays (dispatching based on whether or not the argument is an array)

Comment: If you're doing enough of these operations for their speed to matter, you should probably be using arrays and NumPy whole-array operations instead of `math.whatever`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the functions from the `math` module for scalars is perfectly fine. The [`numpy.arccos`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/97c35365beda55c6dead8c50df785eb857f843f0/numpy/lib/scimath.py#L435) function is likely to be slower due to

- [conversion to an array (and a C data type)](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/97c35365beda55c6dead8c50df785eb857f843f0/numpy/lib/scimath.py#L171)
- [C function call overhead](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/66873577afe02786fb5484051babd4485c7cb39c/numpy/core/code_generators/generate_umath.py#L561)
- conversion of the result back to a python type

If this difference in performance is important for your problem, you should check if you really can't use array operations. As [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35183787/in-python-is-math-acos-faster-than-numpy-arccos-for-scalars#comment58084900_35183787) said in the comments, arrays are what `numpy` really is great at.